# iOS Executing loop until certain condition is met of specified time has passed?

Tags: ios, infinite-loop

As the title states, i have a while loop that will be executed until certain condition is met, or until 5 seconds have passed.

What is the best way to solve this? I have seen some simple tutorial about `NSTimer`, but it seems to me that selector that is fired within `NSTimer` will be executed after time interval specified no matter what. I only need to execute it if condition is not met...

Comment: couldn't you just use a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an NSTimer scheduled action store the timer and if you reach your what you wanted to achieve deactivate this timer so that it doesn't trigger the action.

Basically:

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(yourAction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 some code

//for deactivating the timer
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

You could start the NSTimer on the main thread (to ensure above code works) with this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerMethod) withObject:someOrNoObject waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I have tried executing this action but nothing happens. Could be because I am scheduling the timer in background thread, which i got by executing  [self performSelectorInBackground:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#>]

Comment: Did you store the reference to this timer? Or just post the relevant code snippets

Comment: I do write something like this: NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; but timer fired is never called

Comment: If the reference of the Timer is just in your background task it doesn't help you, check wether your timer reference is nil when you call invalidate

Comment: Nope its not nil, but i did found something interesting - in order to run timer you should have nsrunloop instance, that is only present in main thread, but not in threads that you create. Hot to deal with this i am not sure...

Comment: You could just start your timer on the main thread like this [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerMethod) withObject:someOrNoObject waitUntilDone:NO];